# Export SQL Server view into text files

Tags: sql-server, view, export

I need export to txt file one view on SQL Server database and I have tried :

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options',
 1 RECONFIGURE EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',
 1 RECONFIGURE EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable " 
 queryout "D:\\public\\output.txt" -T -c -t;'
```

But the error is:

```
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
Invalid object name 'myDb.myTable'.
```

Maybe you can not export SQL Server views into text files ?

Comment: `FROM myDb.dbo.myTable` **database_name.schema_name.table_name** or `FROM myDb..myTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL Server` you have multipart names **database_name.schema_name.table_name**.

Change your

```
SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM myDb.dbo.myTable
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM myDb..myTable
```

If you use different schema than default `dbo` use it instead.